# Find conflicting versions between package-lock.json and yarn.lock when both exists

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg, package-lock.json

I have some cases where in one project I have both `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock` files (this is done unintentionally, but it's not relevant at the moment) - In order to remove one of them (personally I prefer leaving the `yarn.lock` file) - I first need to know what are the differences between them, for that I can see two different solution :

1. Finding difference in version between the two files (packages that are listed in both in different version / packages that are listed in only one of lock files)
2. Delete both lock files, and generate a new one from the packages that are actually installed in my `node_modules` folder

I found no command to do both (I'd expect yarn to provide that, since yarn is "npm compatible" and not the other way around)

I found `yarn generate-lock-entry` whose name suggest that it should be relevant for my 2nd option - but it has nothing to do with that

Any Idea?
Thanks!